# Why TableRows with TextViews are not being displayed inside TableLayout if the number of TableRows exceeds a certain number?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

This is my first attempt to write a "simple" android app. Sadly I recognized that my app that displays content from a csv file looks different on my galaxy sIII mini comparing to the AVD. The weird thing is that in the AVD all - for example 400 - entries in the csv file could be displayed properly. In contrast to my smartphone where the TableLayout composed of TableRows including TextViews don't show any values (no error occurs). If I change the number of lines in the csv file (from 400 to 80 for instance) the TextViews are being displayed on the smartphone screen. A strange thing is also that the content which seems not being displayed is there but not visible. If I click on the screen of my smartphone the click event is being called and I can see in the log output that the values are being printed out to the console.

The TableRows and TextViews are being added at runtime. The number of TextViews depends on the number of columns and the number of TableRows depends on the entries in the csv file. The "firstAddressRow" is filled with the column headings.

Here is my layout definition of the activity object being used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/background_panel">
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="40dp" android:onClick="updateCanvas" android:text="Update"/>
    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:orientation="vertical">
            <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
                                  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TableLayout
                        android:id="@+id/addressTable"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:alpha="0.9">
                    <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/firstAddressRow">
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone know where my mistake is? I thought that maybe I have to refresh or update the layouts and views again but no "invalidate" or update function was successful.

The button I inserted at the top was just an experiment. The updateCanvas method only deletes some TableRows and the weird thing is that if enough TableRows have been deleted I see the TextViews again. And I know I already mentioned it in the introduction but with the AVD it is working fine. I would really really appreciate it if somebody could help me out... It's so frustrating...

If you need more information or more code than please let me know.

Comment: Firstly, nested scrolling Views are finicky at best, and oftentimes just don't work at all. Secondly, using a `TableLayout` as you are causes every `View` in it to be loaded simultaneously, and can lead to poor performance and bigger overhead. Have you considered using a `ListView` instead?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply! Yes, I did consider using a ListView but I thought that it would be more natural to take a TableLayout because the CSV file acutally is like a table. Furthermore I wanted to be able to click on every TextView. Is it possible to create a ListView with several columns or do I need a ListView for every column in my CSV file?
I continued my search on this issue and found out that some people have similar problems which are related to the insufficient amount of heap space. Do you have experience on that? Could that be possible?

Comment: Using a custom `Adapter` and row layout, you can create a `ListView` that looks like a spreadsheet, which is what I assume you're going for. The `TextView`s just need to have consistent sizes across rows to create a columnar effect, and each will respond to click events like any other `View`. The upshot of a `ListView` is that it recycles rows and their child `View`s; i.e., pretty much only the `View`s you can see on screen are loaded, which cuts down on overhead. The downside is that Android does not yet, AFAIK, have a `View` or combination thereof that can reliably scroll bidirectionally.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I misspoke in my last comment. A `WebView` handles bidirectional scrolling beautifully, but if you were to go that route, you'd have to implement your table and and least some of the event handling in JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for your additional comment. I tried a new design but I did not implement it yet. I'll try to take a `PageViewer` with `GridView`s inside. So I'll try to split up the amount of columns and the user can swipe through the columns.
The rendering issue still bothers me. Although data is not being displayed on my phone with `TableLayout` it is there because I can interact with the `TextView`s. Do you have experience in debugging rendering issues? Where could I start? It's just for the sake of interest. I want to find out why `TableLayout` doesn't work properly.

Comment: With dynamically created `TableLayout`s it's usually a matter of using the wrong type of `LayoutParams`. I'll have to see the code. First thing I'd do, though, is test it without the `ScrollView`s, just the `TableLayout` by itself, to make sure those aren't causing it.